# mysql - Select all where date variable is between STARTDATE column and ENDDATE column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date, date-range

I have a form where a user selects a month and views all records that fall within that month. The database records a start date and an end date.

I need to query for all records that are between that start date and end date. So I can't query for `MONTH(Data.startdate) <= $month` because I need it to be BETWEEN the start and end dates. So essentially I'd need it to be:
**startdate < month < enddate**

So if a user selects "February", I need to not only include the records where the startdate=2 but I need to select all those where February is between the start date and end date.

I can't come up with a way for `BETWEEN` to work for this since I think that requires the column name to be first and the date range to be variables.

**UPDATE**
Since I am looking for multiple months, I had to use a combination of an answer below within a set of parentheses with OR in between.

The query for reference: `SELECT * FROM Data INNER JOIN Section on Data.section_id = Section.section_id INNER JOIN`Type`on Data.type_id = Type.type_id INNER JOIN Company on Data.company_id = Company.company_id INNER JOIN Materials on Data.materials_id = Materials.materials_id INNER JOIN Marked on Data.marked_id = Marked.marked_id WHERE Section.section_id = 1 AND YEAR(Data.data_startdate) = 2015 AND ((MONTH(Data.data_startdate) <= 1 AND MONTH(Data.data_enddate) >= 1) OR (MONTH(Data.data_startdate) <= 2 AND MONTH(Data.data_enddate) >= 2)) ORDER BY Data.data_startdate, Data.section_id, Data.type_id ASC`

When I loop through the results, however, the result only displays once because it is just one record. How do I loop through the results and show something like what is below without having to loop through the entire results array multiple times and check each result against the month. I want to display:
ALL RESULTS FALLING IN JAN
ALL RESULTS FALLING IN FEB

Right now the results are displayed as:
ALL RESULTS STARTING IN JAN
ALL RESULTS STARTING IN FEB

Is there perhaps a way to separate the queries into sub arrays or something?

For instance, if I select just Feb, none of the results that have it starting in Jan will display.

Comment: There's this word "AND" that's very helpful in SQL.

Comment: Please clarify two things: When the user picks a month, do you want events in that month from any year past or future?  Second, please confirm that you want a record to be selected if any part of the interval (start -- end) lies in the chosen month.

Comment: I think that besided "month box" you might consider adding a "year box", because with month only, when user picks "February", he/she might get (depending on your db data) the following dates: `2009-02-01`, `2013-02-05` and also `2014-02-11`. However this might be your expected behaviour.

Comment: I query by year also, but I was trying for a simpler example of what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE MONTH(Data.startdate) <= $month
AND MONTH(Data.enddate) >= $month
```

Comment: This definitely helps with the problem, but how would I loop through the results and display all records that fall within each month instead of just displaying all that start in that month.

Comment: Hmm... that's quite different than the original question. Might be worth asking a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE $month BETWEEN MONTH(startDate) AND MONTH(endDate)
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error. If I put the variable before `BETWEEN`, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which error you have, because i tested this with a similiar table i have with date ranges, and it works